# Matplotlib downloads to override folder

Tags: qgis, matplotlib

Just completed install of QGIS (2.0.1 Dufour) on a Macbook Pro running on Mavericks via Kyngchaos download page. However, when downloading Matplotlib for the install, while everything ended up the correct python site package (2.7), the matplotlib wound up in a folder within the 2.7 site package called matplotlib-override. Does anyone have an explanation? When in the 'override folder QGIS could not find Matplotlib, but once removed and bumped up a level to the site package (2.7) folder QGIS installed cleanly (still running it through its paces for functionality).

Comment: I'd like to know this as well. My python site packages also show this as well as numpy-override folder and path. Attempts to update or modify using pip have proven impossible.